# AngularJS unit tests for database service

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, ionic-framework, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I want to add some test cases for my angularjs application specially for the database service.

Well the problem is that I can't really open the database in my unit test.

My testcase looks like this:

```
describe("DatabaseCreateService‚", function () {
  var DatabaseCreateService,cordovaSQLite;

  beforeEach(module("starter.services"));
  beforeEach(module("ngCordova"));
  beforeEach(module("ionic"));

  beforeEach(inject(function (_DatabaseCreateService_, $cordovaSQLite) {
    DatabaseCreateService = _DatabaseCreateService_;
    cordovaSQLite = $cordovaSQLite;
  }));

  it("should create the table cg_local_values", function () {
    var db = DatabaseCreateService.initDB("Test.db");
    expect(db).toBeDefined();
  });
});
```

My factory looks like this:

```
var initDB = function(dbName) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    if (window.cordova) {
      db = $cordovaSQLite.openDB(dbName);
      return db;
    }else{

      db = window.openDatabase(dbName, '1', 'my', 1024 * 1024 * 100);
      console.log(JSON.stringify(db));
      return db;
    }
  });
};
```

Well I get this error if I run karma start:

```
Expected undefined to be defined.
        at Object.<anonymous> (pathToTests/tests/services/DatabaseServiceTest.js:42:16)
Chrome 46.0.2490 (Mac OS X 10.11.1): Executed 24 of 24 (1 FAILED) (0.183 secs / 0.146 secs)
```

As karma test browser I use the Chrome browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I found out that I have to save the db in beforeEach after ionicPlatform is ready. Now it looks likes this and its working:

var DatabaseCreateService,cordovaSQLite,ionicPlatform,rootScope,q;
    var db=null;

```
beforeEach(module("starter.services"));
beforeEach(module("ngCordova"));
beforeEach(module("ionic"));

beforeEach(inject(function (_DatabaseCreateService_, $cordovaSQLite,$ionicPlatform,$rootScope,$q) {
  DatabaseCreateService = _DatabaseCreateService_;
  cordovaSQLite = $cordovaSQLite;
  ionicPlatform = $ionicPlatform;
  q = $q;
  rootScope = $rootScope;

  ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    db = window.openDatabase("Test.db", '1', 'my', 1024 * 1024 * 100);
  });
}));
```